# Apache solr 5.3.1 out of memory

Tags: postgresql, memory, solr

i'm new to solr, though i'm struggling for a few days to run full indexing on a postgreSQL 9.4 DB on a entity with about 117.000.000 entries.
I'm using solr 5.3.1 on Windows 7 x64 with 16 GB of RAM. I'm not intending to use this machine as a server, it's just some kind of prototyping i'm at.

I kept getting this error on JDK x86 with just starting solr as `solr start` without any options. Then i tried:
`solr start -m 2g` which results in solr not coming up at all
`solr start -m 1g` makes solr start, but after indexing about 87.000.000 entries it dies with an out of memory error.

It is exactly the same point at which it dies without any options, though at the admin dashboard I see JVM heap is full.

So, since solr warns me anyway to use a x64 JDK i did and now use 8u65. I started solr with 4g Heap and started full import again. Again after 87.000.000 entries it threw the same exception. But the heap isn't even full (42%), neither is RAM or SWAP.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for this behaviour?
Here is my data-config

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource 
type="JdbcDataSource"
driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"
user="user"
password="secret"
readOnly="true" 
autoCommit="false" 
transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" 
holdability="CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT" />

<entity name="hotel"
query="select * from someview;"
deltaImportQuery = "select * someview where solr_id = '${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
deltaQuery="select * from someview where changed > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}';">

<field name="id" column="id"/>
... etc for all 84 columns
```

in `solrconfig.xml` i have defined a `RequestProcessorChain` to generate a unique key while indexing, which seems to work.

in `schema.xml` there again are 84 columns with type, indexed and other attributes.

Here is the exception i'm getting, they are in german but the first one is saying "error 48" and the other "out of memory"

```
getNext() failed for query 'select * from someview;':org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Speicher aufgebraucht
Detail: Fehler bei Anfrage mit Größe 48.
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:62)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.hasnext(JdbcDataSource.java:416)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.access$500(JdbcDataSource.java:296)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.hasNext(JdbcDataSource.java:331)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase.getNext(EntityProcessorBase.java:132)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:74)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Speicher aufgebraucht
Detail: Fehler bei Anfrage mit Größe 48.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.fetch(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2113)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.next(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1964)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.hasnext(JdbcDataSource.java:408)
... 12 more
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a comment: Perhaps there is a record whose content size exceeds field schema definition on solr.

Comment: The error seems to be thrown by the JDBC postgres driver, so it might  be a consequence of your result size. DIH does have a batch size property that you can try to adjust, or you can dump it into CSV or JSON and then try to index that instead.

Comment: thank you, JDBC really was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by MatsLindh it was a JDBC error. Meanwhile i worked with hibernate search and experienced the same error at exactly the same time (near 87.000.000 indexed entities). The trick was to commit more often.

So at this case i tried several things at one time and it worked (don't know which option exactly did the trick):

```
1. set maxDocs for autoCommit in solrconfig.xml to 100.000. I believe that the default setting for committing is something at 15 seconds if no new documents are added, what actually happens all the time, until heap space runs full.
2. Set batchSize for the postrgreSQL JDBC Driver at 100 (Default is 500).
3. Changed the evil 'select * from table' to 'select c1, c2, ..., c85 from table'
4. Updated the JDBC Driver from 9.4.1203 to 9.4.1207
5. Updated Java to 1.8u74
```

I think it worked due to 1. and/or 3., I will do some further testing and update my post.

While i was trying the indexing with hibernate search I could see that the allocated RAM for PostgreSQL Server was freed at commit, so the RAM never was an issue again. It didn't happen here and the DB Server was at 85 GB RAM in the end, but kept on working.